# is there a way on how i can find the area of the octagon formed by the equilateral triangles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

is there a way on how i can find the area of the octagon formed by the equilateral triangles?

Comment: nothing, because i dont know how i can solve it

Comment: Initially I thought you meant _all_ the shaded area (which is an octagon), but I suppose actually you meant just the darkest shaded area (which is a convex octagon)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The octagon consists of eight triangles of equal area.
Each of them has an area of ${3-\sqrt3}\over 4$.
So ...

In answer to @Mark, I found the intersection of the following two lines: 
1. the line connecting $(0\mid \sqrt3)$ and $(1\mid 0)$ 
2. the line connecting $(0\mid 1)$ and $(\sqrt3\mid 0)$. 
That intersection is $\left({{3-\sqrt3}\over 2}\mid{{3-\sqrt3}\over 2}\right)$. 
The area of the triangle defined by vertices $(0\mid 0)$, $(0\mid 1)$ and
$\left({{3-\sqrt3}\over 2}\mid{{3-\sqrt3}\over 2}\right)$ is
$abs\left({1\over 2}\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
{{3-\sqrt3}\over 2}&{{3-\sqrt3}\over 2}&1\\
\end{vmatrix}\right)$ or ${{3-\sqrt3}\over 4}$.

Comment: but sir, what method was applied to get the area of one triangle?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Hint: it is easy to see what the angles and one side of the red triangle are.

Comment: is the bigger triangle/original triangle, an equilateral  or isosceles triangle?

Comment: (Unlike you) I drew it so that equilateral triangles look equilateral! The only triangle with the topmost point in the figure as vertex is equilateral. :)

Comment: ok sir, but i was just a little bit confused.because in my illustration, i use geogebra to have accurate measurements, so it seems  that i cannot form triangles like the red one from your figure,

Comment: Your $x$ and $y$ scales are different! That is why your figure looks unsymmetrical.

Comment: ok thanks., i'll draw it again